# How to make sure the MultiResourceItemReader refreshes the resources each time the job is executed

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, task

I have a java application which makes use of spring task scheduling and batch jobs. I am relying on `MultiResourceItemReader` in the `job` to read some files from a directory, process them, and remove those files. An external process is responsible to put new files periodically in that directory. But the problem is that each time the `job` runs, it tries to read the same file resources which were present at the time of launching the application and hence fails because those resources are gone and new files are there now.

The question is, how do I configure the application so that the resources property is evaluated for every scheduled execution of the given `job`.

The relevant beans are pasted below:

```
  <bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:/opt/data/*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="testFlatFileItemReader" />
  </bean>

  <batch:job id="MyJob">
    <batch:step id="readandstore">
      <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="oracleItemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
      </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
  </batch:job>

  <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.myapp.Scheduler">
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="job" ref="MyJob" />
  </bean>

  <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="*/30 * * * * *" />
  </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem I posted myself after having received no response on it for almost a week.

I removed the resources property of `multiResourceReader`, and added a `StepListener` to the listeners under `<batch:tasklet>` which implements `StepExecutionListener`. This listener has two methods, one is called before the step execution and the other after the step execution. The `StepListener` accepts a property named `filePattern` the value for which will be similar to what you'd have provided to resources property of `multiResourceReader` before. Here is how the updated beans look like:

```
  <batch:job id="MyJob">
    <batch:step id="readandstore">
      <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="oracleItemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
        <batch:listeners>
          <batch:listener ref="StepListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
      </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
  </batch:job>

  <bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="delegate" ref="csvFileItemReader" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="StepListener" class="com.myapp.StepListener">
    <property name="filePattern" value="file:/opt/data/*.csv" />
  </bean>
```

And here is how the com.myapp.StepListener looks like:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class StepListener implements StepExecutionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StepListener.class.getName());
  private Resource[] resources;
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  private String filePattern;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public void setFilePattern(String filePattern) {
    this.filePattern = filePattern;
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    MultiResourceItemReader reader = (MultiResourceItemReader) applicationContext.getBean("multiResourceReader");
    try {
      resources = applicationContext.getResources(filePattern);
      reader.setResources(resources);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to set file resources to bean multiResourceItemReader", ex);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    if (stepExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED)
            && stepExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED)
            && resources.length > 0) {

      for (Resource resource : resources) {
        try {
          File oldFile = new File(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
          File newFile = new File(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath() + ".processed");
          FileUtils.copyFile(oldFile, newFile);
          oldFile.delete();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Encountered problem when trying to remove the processed file(s)", ex);
        }
      }
    }

    return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The bean multiResourceReader's scope is singleton, so only 1 will every be created. When that bean gets created the value of resources is resolved.

If you set the scope of the bean multiResourceReader to step it should also fix your problem. Then a new bean will created every time the step is executed.

Comment: I found out that this is indeed true, however you need to define the resources as an explicit property, if you use the 'p' namespace for defining the resources property the resources are not reloaded even if the bean is step scoped.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the tag "step" in the configuration bean named "multiResourceReader":

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to extend `MultiResourceItemReader` and override `open()` method and call `setResources()` just before calling `super.open()` method.

```
public class CustomMultiItemReader<T> extends MultiResourceItemReader<T> {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PrestoMultiItemReader.class);
    
    private String filePattern;

    public CustomMultiItemReader() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        Assert.notNull(filePattern, "filePattern must be set");
        try {
            ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
            Resource[] resources = patternResolver.getResources(filePattern);
            super.setResources(resources);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("No resources to read.", e);
        }
        super.open(executionContext);
    }

    public void setFilePattern(String filePattern) {
        this.filePattern = filePattern;
    }
}
```

You can call `CustomMultiItemReader` as below. You don't need to call `setResources()`.

```
public CustomMultiItemReader<T> customMultiItemReader() {
    String filePattern = "file:/...";
    CustomMultiItemReader<T> reader = new CustomMultiItemReader<T>();
    reader.setDelegate(reader()); //reader to delegate here
    reader.setFilePattern(filePattern);
    reader.setStrict(true); 
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've face the same problem but I solved with another aproach, maybe could be helpful, I'm working with FlatFileItemReader but the issue is the same.

The solution was using a ref in property resource with a bean that handle with jobParams, this way every time step start again it is a new instance with a fresh value, the following code it is how I do it:

```
<bean id="customFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="resource" ref="customFile"/><!-- avoid use directly jobParams here -->
<property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />
<property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
<property name="comments" value="*, \u001A" />
<property name="lineMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="br.com.sample.batch.CustomFieldSetMapperSIAW"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

```
<bean id="customFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
<constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[arquivoGSIN]}"></constructor-arg>
```